# Is there a way to use the Platstore's Dynamic Delivery to download the native libs (.so) at runtime after install?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, android-native-library, dynamic-delivery

As the question says, can I use the Dynamic delivery feature to deliver the .so files that my app uses after installation? My .so files are 15 MB in size and this causes the app's size to increase two-fold.

If not , is there any other way I can provide the native libs to the app during runtime? The [Developer Program Content](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10355942?visit_id=637496712214145985-1376649114&rd=4) is pretty clear about this though:

*An app distributed via Google Play may not modify, replace, or update itself using any method other than Google Play's update mechanism. Likewise, an app may not download executable code (e.g. dex, JAR, .so files) from a source other than Google Play. This restriction does not apply to code that runs in a virtual machine and has limited access to Android APIs (such as JavaScript in a webview or browser).*

*Here are some examples of common violations:
Apps or third party code (e.g., SDKs) that download executable code, such as dex files or native code, from a source other than Google Play.*

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a dynamic feature module which can contain native libraries.
The feature module is just like an android library which can contain code, assets and other resources.